How can i add upColor and down Color in series of scatter stock hichart?
Below is jsfiddle link of my chart. I want to set colorUp green and down to red. I added color and colorUp properties in series but not working. I don't know how can i achieve that.
Here is jsFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/pe4dqk57/
(async () => {

// Load the dataset
const data = await fetch(
    'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json'
).then(response => response.json());

const volume = [],
    dataLength = data.length;

for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
    volume.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][5] // the volume
    ]);
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                addPopupEvents(this);
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        },
        height: '80%',
        resize: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        },
        top: '80%',
        height: '20%',
        offset: 0
    }],
   navigator:{
   enabled: false
   },
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: volume
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1
    }],
   
});

})();

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First of all, you have used the dotnethighcharts tag, but this is not an official integration. Instead, use Highcharts .NET. From the provided image, I can tell that you will need to use Highstock with two series: scatter and column. Here is a very basic demo you can base your code on: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yjpwr6hs. You will find all the information in the API and docs, but in case of more specific questions, do not hesitate to provide your code.

@magdalena Thank you for your help, how can i setup upcolor and down color?

This is what i did to show upCoror and down color in scatter stock chart
data: volume.map(function (point, i) {
if (i === 0 || point[1] > volume[i - 1][1]) {
    return { x: point[0], y: point[1], color: 'green' }; // Higher or first point
} else {
    return { x: point[0], y: point[1], color: 'red' }; // Lower
}

})
I just passed data in series using map method and it working fine.
